# Labels lost when moving the Neo4J db from a computer to another

Tags: java, neo4j

I and my collegues are using **Neo4J 2.0 beta** in a Java project. We got some problem with labels. In particular, we have created a database on a local machine. Then we have made a copy of all the files from the db (via compressed file) and we put the copyied files in another machine (say a *production machine*). While on the first machine we can see the labels on the nodes, in the second machine nodes and labels are separated, i.e. we have the list of nodes and the list of labels, but if we query with Cypher for nodes with specific labels nothing is returned.

For the sake of completeness, I report the code that we used to add the labels to the nodes and the query used to retrieve the nodes.

Somewhere we init the `GraphDatabaseService`.

```
GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
```

Then we create nodes by resorting to a unique id and when we create the new node we attach a label to it, e.g. to explain that the node is a `user`.

```
try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
      user_factory = new UniqueFactory.UniqueNodeFactory(graphDb, "users") {
          @Override
          protected void initialize(Node created, Map<String, Object> properties) {
              created.setProperty("id", properties.get("id"));
              created.addLabel(DynamicLabel.label("user"));
      };
      tx.success();
}
```

Now, if we run a Cypher query like the following

```
try (Transaction ignored = db.beginTx()) {
    result = engine.execute("match (n:User) return n.id");
    for (String id : Result.getColumn(result, "n.id")) {
       System.out.println("USER ID "+id);
    }
}
```

we get no results on the second machine, whilst on the first machine we can get the whole list of nodes labelled as users.

Any idea? Are we missing something.

Comment: Did you happen to copy your database from a machine w/2.0 milestone build to a machine w/2.0 RC1 build?

Comment: No, the version is the same (2.0.0-M06).

Comment: Can you query for a user node by property and list its labels, something like `MATCH (n) WHERE n.id = {id} RETURN labels(n)`, to confirm that the labels are there? (There's a typo ['user' vs. 'User'] in the code you post, but maybe that's just an example and not the case in your actual code?)

Comment: I get as a result the label value. Yes, mine was "an example". In practice I manually replaced the original node type (doctor) with the example node (user). Finally, I report that labels on relations are still there.

Comment: @jjaderberg Clearly, I don't get the label value in the production machine. There nothing is returned, but the list of labels is shown in the web interface.

Comment: If the labels are not there at all it sounds like something went wrong when you copied. Anything in the logs when starting neo4j? File permissions ok for db files on production machine? Sometimes compressing and copying messes that up.

Comment: I don't know what's going on! Everything seems to be ok! Maybe we have some problem with labelling in the code! We don't understand.

Comment: Browser can show old cached labels even if they're no longer in the database. If `labels(n)` returns nothing, then there are no labels there for n.